# Vector Space Operator such that $T^9 = T^8$ but $T \neq T^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a Vector Space Operator such that $T^9 = T^8$ but $T \neq T^2$,

I rewrote this as 
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} T(T^8-I) & = & 0 \\ 
T(T-I) & \neq & 0 \end{array}\right.
\implies (T^8 = I) \wedge (T \neq I).$$
For the life of me I can't find an example of this.
Thanks :)

Comment: Weel, let us discuss that. Immediatelly, $T$ can't be inversible.

Comment: I don't follow the logic of the last two lines. In any case, notice that any nonzero matrix whose square is the zero matrix satisfies this condition.

Comment: @Travis I guess he tried to make a system of equations.

Comment: @Travis I was just trying to specifically spell out what I noticed so that it didn't seem like I hadn't put any effort in at all

Comment: Can you find a linear transformation for which $T\neq 0$ but $T^2=0$?

Comment: Yeah I just looked at another stackexchange post and found $(0,1\\0,0)$ as an example. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $T$ satisfies $T^9=T^8$, if and only if the minimal polynomial of $T$ divides $x^9-x^8=x^8(x-1)$. Since we don't want that $T^2=T$, we must pick a $T$ with minimal polynomial equals to $x^k(x-1)$, with $k>1$. By the Jordan form, we have that the operator given by
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$ 
has minimal polynomial equal to $x^2(x-1)$, so it satifies what we want.

Answer (score 3):

Nilpotent matrices of order 8 (matrices $A$ for which $A^8=O$ but $A^n\ne O$ for $n<8$) will satisfy the requirements. One such example is the 8×8 [shift matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix) with ones on the superdiagonal or subdiagonal and zeroes everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the generalized answer

Answer (score 3):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0&1 \\
0&0
\end{array}
\right)
$$